# my firebase real time is null and i need help to solve this problem in my code

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble sending user data from the sign-up activity code to real-time. I've tried different approaches and made sure all connections are correct, but the information is still not reaching real-time. The Gmail I'm using only reaches authentication. I suspect the issue is with my code. Here are the relevant code snippets:

java sign up

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;

ActivitySignUpBinding binding;
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

ProgressDialog dialog;
EditText emailEditText;
EditText passwordEditText;
EditText phoneEditText;
EditText firstNameEditText;
EditText lastNameEditText;
EditText CompassE;
private String email;
private String password;
private String phone;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String repass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(sign_up.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Created Account");
    dialog.setMessage("We created your account");

    binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    emailEditText = binding.Textemail;
    passwordEditText = binding.Textpass;
    phoneEditText = binding.Textphone;
    firstNameEditText = binding.Textname;
    lastNameEditText = binding.Textlast;
    CompassE = binding.repass;




    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            password = passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            phone = phoneEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            firstName = firstNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            lastName = lastNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            repass = CompassE.getText().toString().trim();

            

            // Registration logic
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
                                String refer = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));
                                String referCode = refer.replace(".", "");

                                DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

                                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put("name", firstNameEditText.getText().toString());
                                map.put("phone", phoneEditText.getText().toString());
                                map.put("mail", emailEditText.getText().toString());
                                map.put("password", passwordEditText.getText().toString());
                                map.put("refer code", referCode);
                                map.put("profile", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/escar-95491.appspot.com/o/placeholder.png?alt=media&token=92d82a11-fb0e-4476-9170-a4b99b8baa13\n");
                                map.put("cis", 20);
                                map.put("sps", 4);


                                // Send the data to the database
                                usersRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(map);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(sign_up.this, testMain.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                                Toast.makeText(sign_up.this, "Your account has been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                                databaseRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(map);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(sign_up.this, "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    });
```

users java class

```
public class User {

    String name,email,password,refercode,profile,cis,sps,phone;

    public User(String name,String email,String password,String refercode,String profile,String cis,String sps,String phone){

        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
        this.refercode=refercode;
        this.profile=profile;
        this.cis=cis;
        this.sps=sps;
        this.phone=phone;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRefercode() {
        return refercode;
    }
    public void setRefercode(String refercode) {
        this.refercode = refercode;
    }
    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }
    public void setProfile(String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }
    public String getCis() {
        return cis;
    }
    public void setCis(String cis) {
        this.cis = cis;
    }
    public String getSps() {
        return sps;
    }
    public void setSps(String sps) {
        this.sps = sps;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

the security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: If you run this code in the `onCreate` of your main activity, does anything show up in the database? `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test").setValue(true);` If not, the rest of your code likely doesn't matter.